# "&&" in awk "for" statement

Tags: shell, awk

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
            {x[NR]=$1;y[NR]=$2}
            END{
                for(m=1;m<=NR;m++){
                    for(n=m+1;n<=NR && x[m] == x[n];n++){
                        print NR,m,n,x[m],x[n],y[m],y[n] >> "tmp"
                    }
                }
            }' all_lemma10

awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
            {x[NR]=$1;y[NR]=$2}
            END{
                for(m=1;m<=NR;m++){
                    for(n=m+1;n<=NR;n++){
                        if (x[m]==x[n]){
                            print NR,m,n,x[m],x[n],y[m],y[n] >> "tmp"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }' all_lemma10
```

I am confused with these two awk. I think they should come out with the same result. But it's not the fact. Please help me why.

Comment: I strongly suspect if you simply re-wrote that on multiple lines with white space and indenting the differences would be glaringly obvious. Cramming a naturally multi-line script onto one line does nothing but obfuscate it, especially if you additionally strip away all the other white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to understand the mind-bending details, let me try to explain why the two forms aren't equivalent in *general*:

```
for(n=m+1; n<=NR && x[m] == x[n]; n++)
```

will potentially *stop* iteration *before* `n > NR`, namely as soon as condition `x[m] == x[n]` evaluates to false.

By contrast,

```
for(n=m+1; n<=NR; n++) {if (x[m] == x[n]) ... }
```

will *always* iterate until `n > NR`, and either act on a given iteration or not, depending on whether `x[m] == x[n]` is true or not.